# I need to be able to find the smallest volume in an ArrayList using a for-each loop

Tags: java, arrays, volume

This is the code I have done so far. It creates the `ArrayList` and adds the circles. The volume is stored and is printed in the console. The last thing I have to do is print out the smallest volume using a for-each loop. This is where I'm having difficulties. I could really use some help/advice

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    final int RADIUS_MAX = 100;
        
    int NUM_SPHERES = 4;
       
    List<Sphere> spheres = new ArrayList<Sphere>();
       
    for(int add = 1; add <= NUM_SPHERES; add++) {
        spheres.add(new Sphere(rand.nextInt(RADIUS_MAX)));  
    }
             
    for (Sphere s : spheres) {
        System.out.println(s);      
    }
        
    //TODO: Convert to a for-each loop to find the volume of the smallest sphere
    for (Sphere s : spheres) {
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you please come up with the definition (code) of spheres?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an additional loop. The sphere with the smallest radius will have the smallest volume.  You could store the smallest volume so far (initialized to a very large volume) and update it in either of your existing loops.  I believe the formula for volume is `(4. / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3)`.

Comment: I recommend this approach. It will save you a lot of processing power.

Answer (score 0):

The `volume` formula of the sphere depends from radius like `V <=> R`, so no need to calculate volume each time, because minimal voule will be with minimal radius.

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        final int maxRadius = 100;
        final int totalSphere = 4;

        List<Sphere> spheres = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalSphere; i++)
            spheres.add(new Sphere(rand.nextInt(maxRadius)));

        for (Sphere sphere : spheres)
            System.out.println(sphere);

        Sphere smallestSphere = spheres.get(0);

        for (Sphere sphere : spheres)
            if (smallestSphere == null || sphere.compareTo(smallestSphere) < 0)
                smallestSphere = sphere;

        System.out.println("smallest volume: " + smallestSphere.getVolume());
    }

    public static class Sphere implements Comparable<Sphere> {

        private final int radius;

        public Sphere(int radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public double getVolume() {
            return (4. / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "radius: " + radius;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Sphere sphere) {
            return Integer.compare(radius, sphere.radius);
        }
    }

}
```